# $S$ zero-content set implies closure of $S$ zero-content set

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Let $S$ be a zero-content subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. I want to prove that the closure of $S$ is also a zero-content set of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Since $S$ is a zero-content set, then for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exist sets $P_1,\dots,P_l\subset \mathcal{P}_n$, with $\mathcal{P}_n$ being the collection of all half-open rectangles $P$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, such that $S\subset P_1\cup\dots\cup P_l$. Moreover, if vol$_0:\mathcal{P}_n\to\mathbb{R}$ defined as vol$_0(P):=(b_1-a_1)\dots(b_n-a_n)$, then $\sum\limits_{i=1}^l\mbox{vol}_0(P_i)<\varepsilon$.

My thinking is to consider a sequence $\{x_n\}\subset S$ converging to a limit point of $S$. Then $\{x_n\}$ is a subset of $P_1\cup\dots\cup P_l$. The difficulty that I'm having is how to formally prove that $\{x_n\}$ must necessarily converge in one of $P_i$ ($1\le i \le k$). It will converge to one of the limit points of $P_i$, but it might actually converge outside of $P_i$, since $P_i$ is half-open.

Could it be a good strategy to let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence converging to a limit point of $P_i$, such that this limit point *is* in $P_i$? However, in this case how does one prove that this point is in the closure of $S$?

Answer (score 1):

You have that $S\subseteq \displaystyle\bigcup_{i=1}^{l} P_i$ and every $P_i$ is a half open rectangle, then, $P_i\subset \text{cl}(P_i)$ (where $\text{cl}(A)$ denotes the closure of the set $A$).

In this way, you have that $S\subseteq \displaystyle\bigcup_{i=1}^{l} P_i \subseteq\displaystyle\bigcup_{i=1}^{l} \text{cl}(P_i)$ and we know that the finite union of closed sets is closed, then, $\displaystyle\bigcup_{i=1}^{l} \text{cl}(P_i)$ is closed. Then, the set $S$ is contained in a closed set, hence, $\text{cl}(S)\subseteq\displaystyle\bigcup_{i=1}^{l} \text{cl}(P_i)$ and, clearly, $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{l} \text{vol}_0(\text{cl}(P_i))=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{l}\text{vol}_0( P_i )< \varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon >0$. Thus, $\text{cl}(S)$ is a zero content set.

Comment: But the thing is that cl$(S)$ is a subset of the union of closed "cubes", but not of half-open ones. What needs to be proved is that the closure of $S$ is a subset of half-open "cubes".

Comment: But, is equivalent to be a subset of half open rectangles and to be a subset of closed rectangles.

Comment: How do we know that it is equivalent?

Comment: I think that your definition of a zero content set is a set such that can be covered by a finite collection of half closed rectangles such that the whole volume of these rectangles is less than $\varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon>0$. A half open rectangle is the cartesian product of the intervals of the form $[a,b)$. If a set is content in a closed rectangle $[a,b]^n$, you can consider, with the correct measure, a half open interval such that contains the closed interval. For the other implication, the same, i.e., consider a closed set, with the correct measure, that contains the half open set.

Comment: Moreover, if a set is content in a half open rectangle is clear that is content in a closed rectangle.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you mean that one can pick an $\varepsilon > 0$ and consider the $\varepsilon$-cover of half-open sets. And then pick $\varepsilon' < \varepsilon$ such that the closure of the $\varepsilon'$-cover is contained in the $\varepsilon$-cover?

This sounds like a good idea to me, but since the $\varepsilon'$-cover is made of half-open sets, it is not necessarily true that the closure of the $\varepsilon$-cover is contained in it (there are "walls" with points that are not part of the cover).

Comment: No, the idea is consider the closed cover formed by $P_i=[a_i,b_i]^{n}$ and, take the correct $\gamma>0$ number (depending of $\varepsilon$) and then, build a cover of half open rectangles using the fact that $[a_i,b_i]\subseteq [a_i,b_i+\gamma)$. The trick is take the control of the measure of the closed cover. We can do it because his measure is less than $\varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon>0$.